# Change order of room database with Itemtouchhelper

Tags: android, android-room

I have an app that uses a recyclerview to show the database items. I want to rearrange the items by dragging it with an itemtouchhelper. I figured out how to do this but I don't know how to update my room database.

```
ItemTouchHelper helper = new ItemTouchHelper(new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(ItemTouchHelper.LEFT|ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT|ItemTouchHelper.DOWN|ItemTouchHelper.UP, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {

            int dragFrom = -1;
            int dragTo = -1;
            boolean listChanged = false;

            @Override
            public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder1) {
                int from = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
                int to = viewHolder1.getAdapterPosition();

                if(dragFrom == -1) {
                    dragFrom =  from;
                }
                dragTo = to;
                listChanged = true;

                Collections.swap(mGames, from, to);
                gameAdapter.notifyItemMoved(from, to);

                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
                mGames.remove(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
                Game game = mGames.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
                mGameViewModel.deleteGame(game);
                gameAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onSelectedChanged(@Nullable RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int actionState) {
                super.onSelectedChanged(viewHolder, actionState);

                if(actionState == ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_IDLE && listChanged){

                    //update database

                    listChanged = false;
                }
            }
        });
```

For example I drag item 3 to place 6, then item 4 becomes item 3, 5 becomes 4 and 6 becomes 5.

Is there a special method for this, or do I have to find one my own?

Comment: I believe you would update `Room` on the `clearView` method override. I'm trying to do this myself but having issues because I'm using `PagedListAdapter`.

Comment: Do you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

One easy way (but inefficient for large lists) is that once you get the new list, clear the database and reinsert the items (with new ids (PKeys)). Also make sure to do database operation only when user stop dragging. Also make sure you are not querying items from the database in any specific order.

```
        new ItemTouchHelper(new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(ItemTouchHelper.UP | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {

            boolean drag = false;

            @Override
            public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
                int position_dragged = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
                int position_target = target.getAdapterPosition();

                Collections.swap(mAdapter.getTasks(), position_dragged, position_target);
                mAdapter.notifyItemMoved(position_dragged, position_target);

                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSelectedChanged(@Nullable RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int actionState) {
                super.onSelectedChanged(viewHolder, actionState);

                if(actionState == ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_DRAG) {
                    drag = true;
                }

                if(actionState == ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_IDLE && drag) {
                    Log.d("DragTest","DRAGGGING stop");
                    drag= false;

                    final List<TaskEntry> NewTasksList =  mAdapter.getTasks();

                    AppExecutors.getInstance().diskIO().execute(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mDb.taskDao().deleteAll();

                            for(int i =0; i < NewTasksList.size(); i++){
                                TaskEntry task = NewTasksList.get(i);
                                mDb.taskDao().insertTask(new TaskEntry(
                                        task.getDescription(),
                                        task.getPriority(),
                                        task.getUpdatedAt(),
                                        task.isChecked()
                                ));
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }).attachToRecyclerView(mRecyclerView);
```

Sqlite by default returns by ASC order of primaryKey (ids in my case). So make sure you don't insert new items with old ids.

My TaskEntry.java

```
@Entity(tableName = "task")
public class TaskEntry {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;
    private String description;
    private int priority;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "updated_at")
    private Date updatedAt;
    private boolean checked;

    //When adding new entry to database, id is automatically generated
    @Ignore
    public TaskEntry(String description, int priority, Date updatedAt, boolean checked) {
        this.description = description;
        this.priority = priority;
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
        this.checked = checked;
    }

    //when reading from database
    public TaskEntry(int id, String description, int priority, Date updatedAt, boolean checked) {
        this.id = id;
        this.description = description;
        this.priority = priority;
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
        this.checked = checked;
    }
```

My TaskDao.java

```
@Dao
public interface TaskDao{

//
    @Query("SELECT * FROM task")
    LiveData<List<TaskEntry>> loadAllTasks();

    @Insert
    void insertTask(TaskEntry taskEntry);

    @Update(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void updateTask(TaskEntry taskEntry);

    @Delete
    void deleteTask(TaskEntry taskEntry);

    @Query("DELETE FROM task")
    void deleteAll();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM task WHERE id = :id")
    LiveData<TaskEntry> loadTaskById(int id);
}
```